# Twitter API ansynchronous request in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, twitter, callback

Currently, I am working with the npm "twit" package and I am trying to store the requested data in a variable. I am already familiar with the problem with asynchronous functions in synchronous ones and I understood the concept, too. But the thing is, that in the API-request in twit, there is already a callback-function and I don't really manage it to construct a working function, which does not return "undefined". I already tried to adapt the solutions offered here and many others, but I obviously simply don't get a working solution. I already tried solutions with "setImmediate", but it didn't work either.

```
T.get(request, data, callback);
```

This is a get request via the twit package; it includes the chosen request, the transmitted data and a callback function triggered when data returns. I try to store the data in a global variable, so that I don't need to return any data.

```
var res;

function getId(user) {

     T.get('users/show', { screen_name: user }, gotData);  

}

// Callback function
function gotData(err, reply) {

    if (!err) {
        res = reply;
        console.log(res);
    }
    else {
        res = err;
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is fine, you just can't use the global variable until after your callback. So if you need to use the global variable, you'll need to use a callback in your gotData function and send res as the response

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! How do I use it, I am not sure to be honest. I tried to define a separate callback function "load(input, callback)" with no code to be executed, but the input-value (either reply or err) will be passed to the callback function (an anonymous as second argumen in the call), which sets res equal either reply or err depending on the condition in gotData. But that doens't work either...